# Why was radio and cellphone reception spotty in Jurassic World?

Tags: jurassic-park, jurassic-world

Rewatching *Jurassic World*, I noticed how often they had spotty reception when using radio and cellphone. First when warning Owen Grady and the two park workers examining the Indominus enclosure, later when trying to contact Zach and Gray in their gyrosphere.

Out of universe, that was undoubtedly done to create tension and to further the plot.

But is there an in-universe explanation?

Comment: My reception outside of a big town in a slightly wooded area is patchy, imagine what it's like on a remote island covered in trees.

Comment: I have no canon to support this, but in universe it's likely the same as our universe: lack of cellular infrastructure. Even radios need repeaters to overcome many terrain limitations.

Answer (score 5):

The two boys seem to have lost reception very shortly after the announcement was made to evacuate the north side of the island. Presumably the cell towers were overloaded with calls from the other guests contacting their friends and family to complain. Her reception at all other times was impeccable.

As far as radio reception is concerned, it seem to be patchy on the northern side of the island. You can see from this false-colour topological map that the northern paddock is ringed with small hills and a large volcano, all of which would block or refract radio signals.

[image]